# how to assign static ipaddress (fixed ipaddress) in vmware workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

Iam using vmware workstation12. I have a 2 vm and I installed Ubuntu in it.

The ip address changes automatically in the ubuntu.Last week the IPADDRESS in the first vm was 192.168.56.1 and in the second vm was 192.168.56.2.
But today I got changed to 192.168.56.3 and 192.168.56.4.

Because of this change I need to change lot of thing in my hadoop setup like ssh and name node configuration and lot of things.

Please help me to assign fixed ipaddress to vm.

Comment: the question should be: how to assign static IP in Ubuntu.

Comment: take a look at ubuntu documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

This article would help: https://communities.vmware.com/message/1888335

So, basically, it tells you how to configure the DHCP service for VMWare to mapping IP address with MAC address of the guest VM, therefore the guest VM will always been assigned with the IP address you've specified.

It is like adding this section to the end of vmnetdhcp.conf file (On the host Windows machine. For other OS, such as VM Fuse on macOS or VMWare on Linux or ESXi, the file name/path could be varial, but the setting are expect to be similar):

```
host Win81x86A {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:56:4F:A9;
    fixed-address 192.168.213.10;
}
```

In addition to this, which the article didn't introduce, there's other steps if it doesn't take effect (On Windows):

1. Make sure you've configured the right configuration file. On Windows, Config the configuration file:

   ```
   %%ALLUSERDATA%%\Vmware\vmnetdhcp.conf
   ```
2. Stop the "VMware DHCP Service" and "VMware NAT Service".
3. Clean up the ".leases" file:C:\ProgramData\Vmware\vmnetdhcp.leases
4. Restart the "VMware DHCP Service" and "VMware NAT Service"
5. Start VMWare and run the VM. Or, if already running, issue a DHCP renew command (Linux: sudo dhclient -rv; sudo dhclient -v)

It should be working now.

Comment: Ubuntu. Read it !